# "Resources" folder has a wrong path when used from different sub-project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, localization

I have the following structure:

```
├── Main
│   ├── Controllers
│   │   ├── MainController.cs
│   ├── Startup.cs
├── Common
    ├── Services
        ├── CommonServices.cs
├── Resources
│   ├── Controllers
│   │   ├── MainController.resx
    ├── Services
        ├── CommonServices.resx
```

In the `Startup.cs` I have:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that the path of the resources file is wrong: `Main.Resources.<resource-path>`. I want it to be `Resources.<resource-path>`.

The only solution I came with is combining the two sub-projects, which is the opposite of what I want to achieve in first place.